# What is the probability of drawing 2 red balls out of an urn with replacement by method of counting?

Tags: probability

In an urn, we have 3 Red balls and 4 Blue balls($S=\begin{Bmatrix}
Red, Red, Red, Blue, Blue, Blue, Blue
\end{Bmatrix})$. What is the probability of drawing exactly 2 red balls out of a total of 5 draws with replacement?

My solution without using the method of counting is:

- $P(Red\:Red\:Blue\:Blue\:Blue) = \frac{3}{7} * \frac{3}{7} *
     \frac{4}{7} * \frac{4}{7} * \frac{4}{7} = 0.0342$
- Ways to have exactly 2 Red balls in 5 draws =
  $C\binom{5}{2} = \frac{5!}{(5-2)!2!} = 10$
- So $P(2 Red\:balls) = 0.0342 * 10 = 0.342$

However, I am unable to obtain the same probability of 0.342 by the method of counting:

- Ways to draw 5 balls out of 6 with replacement $=C\begin{pmatrix}
  5+6-1\\ 
  5
  \end{pmatrix} = \frac{(5+6-1)!}{(6-1)!5!} = 252$
- Ways to draw 2 of the Red balls with replacement $=C\begin{pmatrix}
  2+3-1\\ 
  2
  \end{pmatrix} = \frac{(2+3-1)!}{(3-1)!2!} = 6$
- Ways to draw 3 of the Blue balls with replacement $=C\begin{pmatrix}
  3+4-1\\ 
  3
  \end{pmatrix} = \frac{(3+4-1)!}{(4-1)!3!} = 20$
- So $P(2 Red\:balls) = \frac{6 * 20}{252} = 0.476$

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The outcomes counted by stars and bars (*combinations with replacement*) are not equally likely to have occurred.  It is far more likely for you to have gotten one each of several balls than it is to have gotten five of the first type of ball, yet your method incorrectly counts each of these as equally likely.

Comment: How would I account for the difference in the likelihood of the two colored balls in the counting method?

Comment: By not using combinations with replacement... instead, treat order as relevant.  There are $7^5$ different sequences of ball selections (*treating every ball as distinct*) which are equally likely to occur (*as per standard assumptions about the problem*) and $3^2\cdot 4^3\cdot \binom{5}{2}$ of these sequences which have two red balls... exactly the same calculation you did before except phrased as us counting things rather than phrased as us multiplying probabilities.

Comment: Worse than that, $\binom{5+6-1}{5}$ counts distinct arrangement of $5$ indistinct objects into $6$ distinct containers.   What are you even trying to count here?

Comment: @GrahamKemp that would be the number of collections of sorted results of pulling five balls in sequence with replacement.  The "balls" in this case are the separate pulls, the "bins" in this case being which label the ball had (*assuming the balls all had distinct labels*).  The issue, again, is that they are not equally likely.  The number was correct if that were the question being asked, but the calculation is worthless in terms of trying to calculate a probability.

Comment: @JMoravitz It looks like you're correct. I'm feeling stupid here. Can you explain to me the logic behind $3^{2}\cdot 4^{3}\cdot \binom{5}{2}$? Specifically the $\binom{5}{2}$ multiplied at the end and why is the order relevant when there is replacement? Thanks

Comment: Not following some of this discussion. Seems to me it's simple binomial. In R, where `dbinom` is PDF: `dbinom(2,5,3/7)` returns $0.3427143.$ Also code > `10*(3/7)^2*(4/7)^3` returns $0.3427143.$